# Spring @Query with Lower and Wildcards

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, wildcard

This Question refers to Spring Data JPA.

I need a (native) @Query with the Lower Function and Wildcards.
But I dont get it to work.

Here is a oversimplified version of what I am looking for:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM CAR c WHERE LOWER(c.model) LIKE LOWER(%:model%)", nativeQuery = true)
List<Car> findByModelMatching( @Param("model") String model );
```

LOWER(%:model%) -> not working!
LOWER(:model) -> works!

I am aware of that such a query can be easily re-written as:

```
List<Car> findByModelContainingIgnoreCase( String model );
```

But I am not looking for a Named Query.

My Question is: How to combine LOWER (or even UPPER) with WildCards in a @Query!

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `LOWER` function accepts strings, you should write `LOWER('%' || :model || '%')` if you are on Oracle for example.

Comment: Thanks galovics! Works like a charm!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please accept the answer as others might benefit from it.

Comment: ```AND lower(a.lastName) LIKE lower(concat('%',:lastName,'%'))```   works for me. Generated query was the same recommended by @galovics

Comment: this works for MySQL/MariaDB as well. Good workaround for a new bug in Spring or Hibernate where %:model% which used to work no longer does.